# how to set specific ejb jndi names in jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jboss, ejb, jndi

my web application contains a few 2.x stateful and stateless session ejbs. but unlike previous jboss versions (as well as other major app servers), i am unable to specify an ejb jndi name in jboss 7.1.1. i have followed their docs by eliminating jboss.xml in favor of jboss-ejb3.xml, as well as starting the app server in full profile mode.

```
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd
                     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
                  version="3.1"
                  impl-version="2.0">
   <enterprise-beans> 
      <session>
         <ejb-name>MyEJB</ejb-name>
         <jndi-name>MyEJB_JNDI_NAME</jndi-name>
      </session>
   </enterprise-beans>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

however, the **jndi-name** in jboss-ejb3.xml is not taking hold, preventing me from setting my own custom ejb jndi name. does anyone know how to do this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<jndi-name>` is no longer supported in JBoss AS 7. From [this JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3015?focusedCommentId=12651177&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12651177):

> In AS7 we no longer support binding to custom JNDI names for EJBs. So
>   the beans are always bound to the spec mandated java:global, java:app
>   and java:module namespaces. The `<jndi-name>` for the session bean
>   element is no longer supported.

Comment: was this approach implemented in order to comply with j2ee 6 specification? also, because jboss-ejb3.xml schema still supports <jndi-name> node, it is there to specify a jndi name as long as it complies with three prefixes you specified?

Comment: Where do you see it? If you look at the [ejb-jar_3_1.xsd](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd) the `<jndi-name>`is nowhere, but they do mention a `<mapped-name>` with this clarification for session beans: "_...can be used to provide vendor-specific deployment information such as the physical jndi-name of the session bean's remote home/business interface. This element is not required to be supported by all implementations. Any use of this element is non-portable_". It's neither in the [jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd](http://goo.gl/CNSy0)

Comment: you are correct, there is no <jndi-name> in the jboss-ejb3.xml. so i opted for using the following approach in jboss' standalone.xml:

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"><bindings><lookup name="MyJNDI" lookup="java:global/jboss-specific-JNDI"/></binding</subsystem>

Comment: Yea, that works also. Just so you know that the latest spec has opted out custom JNDI names and defined a **standardized global JNDI namespace** (Section 4.4 of the [EJB 3.1 Spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr318/index.html) )

Comment: that's what i figured when i posted my first response to your actual answer. now all i need to make sure is that all other major app servers are following the same.
as for '<mapped-name>', do you happen to know where i can find the best description on how to go about using it within a deployment descriptor. so far, i have not been able to find anything descriptive.

Comment: user1056027's hint about Binding Aliases for EJB JNDI names is documented in 
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Naming+Subsystem+Configuration